# Add all non-empty rows into Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-project, gantt

When I export a Microsoft Project file into Excel using the export tool, the resulting XLSX file has 1 table called `Task_Table1`. Unfortunately that table only includes the header row.
Is there any way to automate adding all non-empty rows into that table, or alternatively making Project include all the lines in the table it creates when exporting?
I'm open to all options, including Excel script and power automate.

***Background***: I'm trying to feed the exported Excel into a Power Automate flow, but I need it to have a proper table in order to use the "get rows in table" step.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this to the [Project Management site](https://pm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @RachelHettinger It's more of a general issue regardless of the source being project, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks!